# Typescript variable underfined inside inner function

Tags: angular, function, typescript, variables, scope

I am trying to access a outer variable inside a function within a function, but it is showing the variable as undefined in my debugger:

```
export class TestClass {
  someObj = [ { id=1 }];

  changeData() {
    const someId = 1;
    const test = {
       attr: function() { return (this.somObj.find(x => x.id === someId ));   }
    };
  }
}
```

this.someObj is undefined. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes. Use an arrow function instead, so `attr: () => { return (this.somObj.find(x => x.id === someId ));   }`

Comment: Also `somObj` is not `someObj`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled `this.somObj`.

You have to refer `this` with **an other variable** before:

```
 changeData() {
    const someId = 1;
    const that = this;
    const test = {
       attr: function() { return (that.someObj.find(x => x.id === someId ));   }
    };
  }
```

As stated by someone else, you can also use an **arrow function**:

```
attr: () => { return (this.someObj.find(x => x.id === someId )); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
someObj = [ { id=1 }];
```

did you mean:

```
someObj = [ { id:1 }];
```

?